# Merge not inserting new values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-merge

I'm trying to use MERGE to insert new values to a table only if they don't already exists in the same table.

This is the query I am using:

```
MERGE [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] AS Target 
USING 
(SELECT [NAME]
    FROM [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] 
    WHERE [NAME]='ThisValuesDoesntExists' AND [STATUS] IS NULL) AS Source
    ON Target.[NAME]= Source.[NAME]
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT ([NAME],[file_first_upload],[upload_date])
        VALUES('ThisValuesDoesntExists',1,DEFAULT);
```

But when I execute it, I get a (0 rows affected) message.

If I execute the "Source" query, I get 0 rows.

```
SELECT [NAME] 
FROM [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] 
WHERE [NAME] = 'ThisValuesDoesntExists' AND [STATUS] IS NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It seems odd that your merging from `TARGET_TABLE` *to* `TARGET_TABLE`.

Comment: You're thinking about it backwards... when you have no rows in your source table, there is no match or not matched. To have a not match you need a row in your source that doesn't exist in your target - you've tried to do it the other way around. If you make your source a static `values` it works.

Comment: [Reasons why not to use `MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) (not sure how many of those are still current bugs) and also [a good reason to yes use `MERGE` in this type of query](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/02/the-halloween-problem-part-3.html) By the way, I would advise an `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` hint on the target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation, you will see that the source data must exist in order to match (or not match) against existing rows in the target table:

> WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] THEN <merge_not_matched>
>
> Specifies that a row is inserted into target_table **for every row
> returned by <table_source>** ON <merge_search_condition> that doesn't
> match a row in target_table, but satisfies an additional search
> condition, if present. The values to insert are specified by the
> <merge_not_matched> clause. The MERGE statement can have only one WHEN
> NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] clause.

The problem you're facing is that your "source" data is not returning anything and so the MERGE query has nothing to match against or insert.

Sample code below to demo:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TARGET_TABLE', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TARGET_TABLE 
GO 

CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(100), file_first_upload BIT, upload_date DATETIME, [STATUS] VARCHAR(100)) 

MERGE [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] AS Target 
USING 
(SELECT [NAME]
    FROM [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] 
    WHERE [NAME]='ThisValuesDoesntExists' AND [STATUS] IS NULL) AS Source
    ON Target.[NAME]= Source.[NAME]
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT ([NAME],[file_first_upload],[upload_date])
        VALUES('ThisValuesDoesntExists',1,DEFAULT);

SELECT * 
FROM TARGET_TABLE 

MERGE [dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] AS Target 
USING (VALUES ('ThisValuesDoesntExistss',1,GETDATE())) AS Source ([Name], [file_first_upload],[upload_date])
ON Target.[NAME] = Source.[Name] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT ([NAME],[file_first_upload],[upload_date]) VALUES (Source.[Name], Source.file_First_upload, Source.upload_date);

SELECT * 
FROM TARGET_TABLE
```